# (#12) analytics_app_events_exports is deprecated for versions v3.0 and higher

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

(PHP)
Using Facebook Export API, I want to download data but when I send post request to v2.* or v3.0 of the api, the errror message written in the title of this question pops up for both of them.

Although according to facebook export api documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/export) the versions below 3.0 are deprecated but they would continue working till August 01, 2018. So why does this error comes for even version 2.* now?

My code is give below.

Can Anyone guide me?

```
$body['access_token'] = $access_token;
$body['start_ts'] = time();
$body['end_ts'] = time()+(60*60);
$end_point = 'analytics_app_events_exports';
$graph_version = 'v2.12';


$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => $app_id,
      'app_secret' => $app_secret,
      'default_graph_version' => $graph_version,
      'default_access_token' => $access_token, // optional
    ]);

 $fb_req = new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($fb->getApp(), $access_token, "POST", $app_id.'/'.$end_point, $body, NULL, $graph_version);
 try{

     $fb_client = $fb->getClient();

     $fb_res = $fb_client->sendRequest($fb_req);

     echo $fb_res;


}
catch(\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e){
     echo $e->getMessage().'<br>';
}
```

Comment: if "analytics_app_events_exports" end-point is deprecated in v3.0 then what is the new end-point in v3.0 of this api because I am unable to find the new end-point.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#fba-4-24: _“On August 1, 2018, we will be removing the Application Analytics App Events Export API. Aggregated data will still be available in the Facebook Analytics interface.”_ - that doesn’t sound like there _is_ going to be a new endpoint, but they want you to access this data via the UI they provide only. Also, it is listed as a “90 Day Breaking Change”, so it should affect all API versions.